# Is Allah knowledge limitless?

Tags: allah

I read in somewhere that someone said Allah knowledge never changes and does not get new knowledge.

But that doesn't make any sense. Isn't Allah omniscient? Shouldn't his knowledge be unlimited and never ending?

Comment: The idea is that Allah already knows everything there is to know. So why must he learn new knowledge to be omniscient?

Comment: @UmH I don't know if I misunderstood but doesn't omniscient imply having infinite knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See. When you accept that Allah has the knowledge of all things, that might be interpreted as **there is no knowledge that is not with Allah**. Consequently, since there is nothing unknown to Him, there is nothing new for him.

Comment: But isn't his knowledge is infinite?

Comment: Allah's knowledge is infinite.